# Can I use -selectRowAtIndexPath: (or anything else) on a UITableView to trigger delegated -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView set up as a navigation controller type deal (like the default in Xcode). I have added an "Add" button which adds an element to the UITableView. When I call `-selectRowAtIndexPath:` on this new row I just added, it will highlight the row, but the next view is not pushed onto the stack. I assume this is because `-selectRowAtIndexPath:` does not trigger the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Is there a way to push the next view onto the stack programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YourViewController animated:YES]
```